# Debian 12 MongoDB MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 Exit Code 2

Tags: linux, mongodb, debian

I am unable to start MongoDB as well as access mongosh

I checked the error code in the status

I have edited security to exactly 2 spaces for enabled and it has not worked

I cannot restart MongoDB, stop or start it, the log ID seems way off as well

#security:
authorization: enabled

Not sure where to look next

Comment: Have a look at the `mongod` log file